# Feeds: How to import content from multiple xml files

Tags: 7, feeds, importing-exporting

I have around 100 xml files. Each xml file contains a single item.

I have created a feeds importer which is working fine for single xml file.

But I don't know if feeds can work with multiple xml files?

Something like loop on the files and import content from each file?

Is it possible with feeds? As I didn't find anything useful.

Comment: Have you read this, https://www.isovera.com/blog/using-feeds-module-bulk-import-drupal-7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## D7

You can import a series of files by using the **File upload** fetcher and enabling the option "Supply path to file or directory directly" on the fetcher settings.

Steps:

1. Select the **File upload** fetcher, enable the option "Supply path to file or directory directly".
   [image: Supply path to directory]
2. Store the XML files to import in the public or private directory. On `Administration > Configuration > Media > File system` (/admin/config/media/file-system) you can see which paths are configured for the public or private file system.
3. On the import form, enter the path to the directory with XML files. If you placed these for example in a folder called "mydir" on the public file system, enter `public://mydir`.

*Public file system*
[image: public file system]

*Import form*
[image: import form]

## D8

In the D8 version of Feeds you would select the **Directory** fetcher. The next steps would be similar as for the D7 version of Feeds.

Comment: I already did what you have answered for D7. And as it is the correct method I will accept your answer. Thank you for the annwer.

Comment: Hello - this is a somewhat old thread, but I have a specific question on D8 use of Feeds to upload multiple XMLs, and do not want to create a separate thread. Using the 'directory' fetcher, it seems like I can supply a directory path. Would this be sufficient? I mean the particular XML filenames under that path can be anything I want as long as they 're XML files? So say I create 'mydir' and use that as 'directory', then having 001.xml and 002.xml would work? And then putting 003.xml at some other time, and running cron again, would initiate an import on all 3 again? (that's what I want)

Comment: @thomas Yes, on each import all files in the folder are expected to be imported. An import *can* take multiple cron runs to complete, because the import task is divided into multiple chunks.